# Sphinx Extensions (numpydoc)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-sphinx, numpydoc

***NOTE Added After:  I finally got numpydoc working.  It was also a python 2 problem. I ran 2to3 on it and now it seems to be working.***

OK, I've spent an entire day trying to get any Sphinx extension to work and am now hoping someone could point out what I'm doing wrong. (Sorry this is a bit long, but maybe more info will help you quickly find the error of my ways).

Sphinx seems to be working as advertised, but I would like to use NumPy style documentation so thought I'd install numpydoc.  In case it matters, I'm using Python 3.3 (winpython 64 bit on windows 7).  I started with the directions [here](http://codeandchaos.wordpress.com/2012/08/09/sphinx-and-numpydoc/) but got the error:

```
Extension error:
Could not import extension numpydoc (exception: cannot import name setup)
```

Googling that I found that some people got around it by using `numpydoc.numpydoc`  No dice. I made sure everything possibly relevant was in my path (as well as added into sys.path in sphinx's `conf.py` file).  I even tried copying numpydoc into sphinx's ext folder and changing the extension string accordingly, still no luck.

At this point I gave up on numpdoc and decided to try napoleon.  Following the installation directions I just `pip install sphinxcontrib-napoleon` and then should be good to go. But alas, no, as napoleon seems to be in 2.x not 3 (though the egg says `Sphinx-1.1.3-py3.3.egg-info` and during installation it says it is installing `sphinxcontrib_napoleon-0.2.1-py3.3-nspkg.pth`.  None-the-less, lots of python 2 code. I tried converting it with 2to3 but then I get a recursion too deep error.

So, I decide to see if I am capable of installing any extension to sphinx.  I essentially at random pick findanything.  Install it as requested and it also fails, this time because of a relpath error (`ValueError: path is on mount 'C:', start on mount 'D:'`).  Which I guess means that it is unhappy that my python installation is on C but my code I'm trying to document (and where I'm trying to run sphinx) is on D (and that I'm running Windows).

So, did I just happen to pick 3 troubled extensions?  Or, if not, what am I doing wrong and (more importantly) how can I do it right so that I get this working?

PS  I'm completely new to Python so please don't assume that I'm not making an incredibly stupid and basic error.

Comment: What do you get when trying to import numpydoc in a python session (in the console)?

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, however...

If you are using Ubuntu 20+, don't install numpydoc via pip. Use

`apt install python3-numpydoc`

instead. Many of the sphinx packages need to be installed this way going forward.